# how to install 32bit dependencies for noarch package on a 64bit box

Tags: centos, yum, 64bit, 32bit

I am on x86_64 Centos 7. I need to install a Package.noarch, but **dependencies must be 32 bit**.

I cannot use:

```
yum install Package.i686
```

since there is no such thing.

Does anyone know how to tell yum to use specific arch for dependencies?

There are ~100 dependencies, so manual approach is not preferable.

Comment: `dnf` adds `--forcearch` that probably does this, but that doesn't help you on centos.

Comment: CentOS 7 : `yum install ./Package.noarch` ... and any 32bits available dependencies will be installed too. There are ~ **1880** i686 packages in the repo : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/ ....

Comment: @KnudLarsen, not sure what you mean. When I try to simply install the package all the dependencies come with x86_64, since Centos is x86_64. There are i686 packages in base/7/x86_64, but yum doesn't try to install them and I can't find a way to tell it to, that's the problem.

Comment: @jordanm, thanks for pointer! I might be able to use it.

Comment: I would simply rebuild the package to "BuildArchitectures: i686" ( Specified in the build file [name].spec ) ... Then the dependencies should be what you want at install time.